# Commuting matrix with rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, rotations

If we suppose that:

$AR=RA$, for any rotation matrix $R$.

Then can we say that $A$ is invariant under rotation?

If so, why?

I tried to do it myself, but I can't seem to get there.

I know what invariant under rotations means, I don't know how I get from what I assumed to invariant under rotation. Or if it is even possible..

Comment: Seems to me a legit question. Anybody care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: Invariant under rotation would mean that $A$ remains same after rotation, so that would be $AR=RA=A$ for all rotations $R$.

Comment: I didn't down vote the question, but the probable reason for it is that you didn't give any indication that you've tried to do the problem yourself.  For all anyone can tell, you're just asking for somebody to do your homework for you.  Give some context; what have you tried, where are you having trouble?

Comment: EDIT. "Invariant under rotation ", they're just words; scrap this idea! Show that "$AR=RA$, for any $R\in O^+(n)$" implies that $A$ is a scalar matrix, when $n\geq 3$. It is easy to show  that the result is false when $n=2$.

Comment: @loupblanc Could you provide the proof? I cannot seem to find it and it drives me mad because I'm sure it is something straightforward.

Comment: @student , cf. my post below.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be s.t., for every $R\in O^+(n)$, $AR=RA$.

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ If $n=2$, then $A$ is in the form $\lambda S$ where $S\in O^+(2)$.

If $n=3$, then $A$ is a scalar matrix.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ $\bullet$ If $n=2$, then $A$ commute with the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}\cos(u)&-\sin(u)\\\sin(u)&\cos(u)\end{pmatrix}$, that is equivalent to $A$ commute with $U=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, that is equivalent to $A\in span(I_2,U)$.

$\bullet$ If $n=3$, let $v$ be a unitary vector. Since $A$ commute with the matrix $Rot(v,\pi/2)$, there is $\lambda$ s.t. $Av=\lambda v$. Thus, any non-zero vector is an eigenvector of $A$ and consequently, $A$ is a scalar matrix.